# Replace file (LICENSE.md) in git history safely

Tags: git, github, git-history-rewrite, filter-repo

I have a repository hosted on GitHub in which I want to replace my `LICENSE` file with another `LICENSE` file in the git history. The original `LICENSE` file was added with the very first commit of the repository.

The repo has open PRs by me and a teammate altough there is not much active development happening right now.

How do I replace the `LICENSE` file in my git repository history **safely**?
I read that there might be issues when rewriting history with other branches as they depend on refs that are not existing anymore when force-pushing changed history to upstream.
Optimally I want all upstream branches to still "work" i.e. I should be able to merge them with a correct diff after rewriting history.

I probably do not have to pay attention to local branches of other co-workers that are not pushed upstream. It would be nice to also not break them but it's not that important really.

I saw that instead of `git filter-branch` `git filter-repo` should be used nowadays. As long as it works safely any solution is okay for me altough I would interested in the "best practice" solution as well ;)

Comment: Retroactively changing the license could land you in trouble. See [this post](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-can-a-project-be-relicensed), in particular... _"Changes are never retroactive. The licenses you granted in the past are granted and cannot be taken back (at least for FOSS)."_

Comment: Filter-branch and filter-repo will have identical "downstream" or "upstream" effects (whatever term you want to use) here: no commit can ever be changed, not even by Git itself, so this kind of history rewrite works by *throwing away the old repository* and making a new, different, incompatible repository. With filter-repo this is more explicit since it takes an input repo (which it doesn't touch) and produces a new, different output repo. Filter-branch works by whacking the existing repo until it's different, with the same outcome except that your original repo is now wrecked.

Comment: For this reason (that filter-branch destroys its input) you should always start by making a clone of an existing repository in which you do the filtering (possibly a mirror clone, although this is painful; filter-repo is much better here).